# How to detect an I2C target's presence/absence as an interrupt?

Tags: i2c, interrupts, detection

Involved in a task to build a test equipment with a ARM M4F microcontroller for the purpose of testing various PCBs. One of the PCBs has I2C compatible current/voltage monitoring chip on it. Is there a possibility to detect this PCB using the I2C communication on plugging it to my test equipment? Just like an external interrupt to the microcontroller, for example?

Comment: You can use large value pull-down resistors on SDA/SCL on the microcontroller side (so that those lines register as low when unconnected). Then when you plug the external PCB in it's pull-up resistors will pull the lines high. If your micro has some form of interrupt on pin change it can detect this.

Comment: @Unimportant  missed out something here in the question. considering the fact that the I2C bus is not idle/ not always pulled up because it is already communication with other I2C slaves. Does your solution still apply?

Comment: It is simple to detect by trying to comnunicate with the chip. If it succeeds, the board has the chip, and if it fails, either the chip is not present or there is something wrong with it.

Comment: @CoppersCopernicus No, you need to be able to sense the transistion from low to high when the board is plugged in. You can either (1) Use a second I2C bus from the micro for this connector (some micro's have multiple buses, or use software I2C). (2) Decouple the I2C bus on the connector using some I2C switch chip (then you can detect plug-in and only connect the buses together when plugin is detected). (3) As Justme suggested, use polling. Periodically try communicating with the chip to see if it's there. Might not be an option as you asked for "interrupt on plug in".

Comment: @Unimportant Thanks for the info. I will try it out :)

Comment: I2C is specified to DC, so unless your implementation has added a timeout, the bus can and will hang if you try and interrogate a non-existent item.

Comment: @PeterSmith yes this is exactly what is happening it is always stuck looking for the slave. Could you please elaborate what you mean by "I2C is specified to DC"?